# OpenGL, Can not Transform using glTranslatef

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I need to make a program using opengl that will have a square move back and forth along the screen. The issue I am having is that the figure is not moving at all.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#define SQ 1

//Used to store the current width and height of window
GLsizei wh = 600, ww = 600;

//Stores the Direction of Movement -1 is negative along
//the axis, and vise versa, 0 will be no movement
static GLfloat dir = 10, dirVH = 1;

//Stores the current top, bottom, left and right value of the square
GLsizei t,b,l,r;

void myinit ()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 600, 0.0, 600);     //Sets a 600x600 viewing Window, can be reshaped
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);   //Sets background color to White
    glColor3f(0,0,0);           //Sets Color to Black
}

void Make_Square()              //Creates the Square List
{
    glNewList(SQ, GL_COMPILE);      //Starts the List
    glColor3f(0,0,0);           //Sets color to Black
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);            //Begins to Draw Polygon
    glVertex2d(200,400);
    glVertex2d(200,200);
    glVertex2d(400,200);
    glVertex2d(400,400);            //Creates a 200x200px Square
    t,r = 400;
    b,l = 200;              //Stores the x,y max and min values of the square, to see if it hit edge.
    glEnd();

    glEndList();                //Ends the List
}

void myReshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h)
{
    /* adjust clipping box */
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, (GLdouble)w, 0.0, (GLdouble)h, -1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    /* adjust viewport and clear */
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
    /* set global size for use by drawing routine */
    ww = w;
    wh = h;
    Make_Square();
}

void demo_menu(int id)
{
    if(id ==1) exit(0);
    else if (id == 3) dirVH = -1;
    else if (id == 2) dirVH = 1;
    else if (id == 4) dirVH = 0;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if(key == 'q' || key == 'Q') exit(0);
}

void ShapeMove(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                        // Set the modelview matrix to be the identity matrix
    glLoadIdentity();
    glCallList(SQ);

    if(dirVH == 1)
    {
    t += 10*dir;
    b += 10*dir;
    glTranslatef(0.0,dir,0.0);
    }
    else if(dirVH == -1)
    {
    glTranslatef(dir,0.0,0.0);
    l += 10*dir;
    r += 10*dir;
    }
    glFlush();
    if(r > ww || l < 0 || t > wh || b < 0)dir *= -1;

    glGetError();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);       // 500 X 500 pixel window
    glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);        // place window - top left on display
    glutCreateWindow("Square Animation");
    myinit();
    glutReshapeFunc (myReshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutDisplayFunc(ShapeMove);
    glutIdleFunc(ShapeMove);        //Functon when nothing is happening
    glutCreateMenu(demo_menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Quit",1);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Move Square Horizontally",2);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Move Square Vertically",3);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Stop Square Movement",4);
    glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

I have tried to remove the transformations from the if statements, and having the program default to move on startup, to no avail. I assume I am using the transformation functions wrong, but I am unsure.

Comment: glTranslatef edits the current transformation. glLoadIdentity makes the current transformation one that doesn't do anything. There is only one current transformation (well actually one for modelview and one for projection), so it is best to not try to use it as a variable - it's best to remember where the square is with your own variables, and then before you render the square, you reset the current transformation to how you want to transform the square.

Comment: glCallList(SQ); needs to be *after* the call to glTranslatef.